# Find a subgroup of $S_4$ that is isomorphic to V, the Klein group.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

So I know that the Klein group is the group with 4 elements that is not cyclic but I'm stuck from there onwards?

Comment: $\{1,(12)(34),(14)(23),(13)(24)\}$.

Comment: The Klein group acts by left multiplication on itself.

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way of going about this:

Every non-identity element in $V_4$ is of order $2$.  Therefore, a good starting point would be to choose your favorite transposition in $S_4$.  Call it $\pi$.  Next, you could choose another transposition and call it $\sigma$.  However, we want to ensure that the composition of $\pi$ and $\sigma$ also has order $2$. This will only happen if $\pi$ and $\sigma$ are disjoint transpositions (why?).

Finish up by considering the subgroup generated by $\pi$ and $\sigma$.

Comment: $V_4$? What is the subscript for? I thought the "V" stood for "4"?

Comment: It's the same $4$ as in $S_4$; in particular it makes the list of transitive subgroups of $S_4$ look more uniform. $C_4, V_4, D_4, A_4, S_4$.

Comment: I think I've seen that notation for it before in textbooks.  Personally, I prefer to just say $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ because it's much more descriptive.  Edit: Qiaochu makes a reasonable point.  In this context, adding the subscript would make sense.

Comment: Does this make sense? Consider the transpositions (1 3) and (2 4). As the subgroups are disjoint and normal to $S_4$, the product of the groups are commutative. Also they are of order two, therefore the product is isomorphic to $Z_2$ X $Z_2$ = V.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by normal.  The argument you want to make is that $(1 2)$ and $(3 4)$ commute because they are disjoint.  (All disjoint cycles commute).  Can you explicitly list the four elements of our group?

Comment: The four elements of the group would be { e, (1 2)(3 4), (1 3)(2 4), (1 4)(2 3)}?

Comment: Careful.  In my original post, I'm saying that we have $(12)$ and $(34)$ as elements by themselves.  One of the elements is $e$ of course.  And the fourth?  Note that Pedro's answer in the comments above is different than what I'm getting at here.

Comment: the fourth element is (12)(34)?

Comment: There we go - because subgroups must be closed under the operation (composition).